# Revalidate and repaint - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, concurrency, event-dispatching

I have a JPanel that I am adding JLabel's to. I then want to remove all the JLabels and add some new ones.

So I do the following:

```
        panel.removeAll();panel.repaint();

        panel.add(new JLabel("Add something new");

        panel.revalidate();
```

This works fine. My problem arises when I start a new thread after this like:

```
    panel.removeAll();panel.repaint();

    (1)panel.add(new JLabel("Add something new");

    panel.revalidate();

    //new thread to start - this thread creates new JLabels that should appear under (1)
    firstProducer.start();              

    try {

            firstProducer.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Then the output from the original JLabels is still visible. I have read that the revalidate process is a long running task and hence the firstProducer thread is getting started while 
the revalidation is going on and a conflict is arising. What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: 1) *"I have a JPanel that I am adding JLabel's to."*  Why?  Having the labels in the GUI with text `""` will make them easier to use, but invisible.  2)  Ensure long running operations are off the EDT, and GUI updates on it.  Implement a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `firstProducer.join`. As stated in the javadoc

> Waits for this thread to die.

So you are blocking the Event Dispatch Thread until your other `Thread` is finished, hence the panel cannot be repainted nor revalidated and you will not see your changes in the UI.

Consult the [Swing concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information